# jQuery attaches only to Existing objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am trying to create a button that onclick adds some new `html` elements to page but `jQuery` doesn't attach to does new objects.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var ask=confirm('Are you sure');
        if(ask){
            var n=jQuery(this).parent();
            var s=jQuery(this).prop('id');
            n.html('Select Picture: <br><input type="file" name="'+s+'" id="'+s+'" required>');
            }
        }
    });
    jQuery(":file").change(function() {
        var na=jQuery(this).val();
        alert(na);
    });
});
</script>
```

now here is a `form` Example for that code:

```
<form>
            <div><img src="image/source"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" required value="1" name="product1">image is ok<br>
            <input type="button" value="change image" id="product1" name="product1b"></div>
<input type="file" name="product2">
</form>
```

So when I click on `button` the `form` changes to this:

```
<form>
<div>
Select Picture: <br>
<input type="file" name="product1" id="product1" required>
</div>
<input type="file" name="product2">
</form>
```

the problem is that jQuery function `jQuery(":file").change(function() {` works for `product2` but not for `product1`, because it was not there on page load and `jQuery` is not attached to it.

Comment: i think you have missed to close bracket properly of **click** event may be you can see in console

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara you're right, thats because I copied codes from my original code and deleted some irrelevant codes so it made that mistake. I'll edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a delegated event when your elements are dynamic:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', ':file', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: This. If your elements don't exist when the DOM is created, there won't be any events attached to it. Delegation is the way to go - this allows you to attach events to a parent in anticipation of your elements being created.